# Swift Compositional Layout contentInsets.top is not working for header

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm creating `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` with `NSCollectionLayoutSection`. I have section with assigned header. Setting `contentInsets` on section works as expected but setting `contentInsets` on header works only for horizontal alignment (leading and trailing are ok). The problem is that top and bottom insets are not working for header. Section has `supplementariesFollowContentInsets` set to `false` and header has `extendsBoundary` set to `true`. Any ideas why it is happening? I can post code but for now I did't because it's very long.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutitem/3199084-contentinsets) it looks like it's not possible to do if you are using `estimated` when creating the layout size.

> The value of this property is ignored for any axis that uses an estimated value for its dimension. For more information, see estimated(_:).

When you are creating `CompositionalLayout` instance you can pass the config with the spacing between the sections:

```swift
let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
config.interSectionSpacing = 50

return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(
    sectionProvider: { ... },
    configuration: config
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to counter this `.estimated` behavior without setting a discrete section spacing value? Some layouts would only want spacing at the bottom of the list and not have that spacing applied to every section.